# Java Return method with math operators and an array

Tags: java

I need to create a function that returns dividors of x/2, put them into a array and returns this array. "x" is a input from a user from diffrent method.

```
public static int[] findDividers(int[] x) {


    int[] array = new int[x/2];
    for(int i=1; i <= array.length; i++) {
        // int c = x/i;
        if (x%i == 0) {
            array[i] = i;   
            System.out.println(i);

        }
    return array;

    }
```

I keep getting error:

> "the operator / and % is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int"

Any suggestions?

Comment: First off, you cannot have an array to be half of the other one in `int[] array = new int[x/2];` You are missing the length

Comment: First:  `x` is an `int[]` and `i` is an `int`.  You cannot do arithmetic on these two since they're not primitives.  Now, to the main thrust:  what are you trying to *accomplish* with `new int [x/2]`?  Do you want a new array that's half as long as `x`?

Comment: Second, you cannot access a whole array to have the modal division by an integer  here `x%i`

Comment: We would need input and output param examples to better understand what you're struggling with

Comment: why are you using int[]x instead of just x?

Comment: I am curious if you understand the problem, are you getting an array of numbers or one number as input? Do you get an array like 1,2,3,4 and should return 2,4 or do you get a number like  8 and should return (8),4,2?

Comment: x is an input integer from a user, let set it to 10. I must find all dividors of x from 1 to x/2 (5 - that should be an array length i guess). Then i need to add all dividors to an array, and return this array with dividors (1, 2, 5).  When i set public static int findDividers(int x) i get "Type mismatch cannot convert from int[] to int" error.

Comment: You should add your last comment to your question since it clarifies what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should be fine if you just modify your argument to the findDividers method. It should be as follows:

```
//Will return dividers of x, not x/2
public static int[] findDividers(int x) { //not int[] x
//if x is of type int[] i.e an array, it makes no sense to
//use the '/' and '%' operators on it. That's why the compiler was
//complaining on your code

int[] array = new int[x/2];
for(int i=1; i <= array.length; i++) {
    // int c = x/i;
    if (x%i == 0) {
        array[i-1] = i;   
        System.out.println(i);

    }

}
return array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, i tried this but im getting "This method must return a results of type int[]" error on method name line.

Comment: I set methot to "public static int[] findDividers(int x)" and i still get "This method must return a results of type int[]"

Comment: I changed my code in the answer after your previous comment. Some curly braces were missing. Try the current code which is in the answer :). Also changed the array assignment in if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion, it will return an array containing the dividers only, so `findDividers(10)` will return the array [1,2,5]

```
public static int[] findDividers(int x) {
    int roof = x / 2;
    int[] values = new int[roof];

    int test = 1;
    int count = 0;
    while (test <= roof) {
        if (x % test == 0) {
            values[count] = test;
            count++;
        }
        test++;           
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(values, count);
}
```